# Can't block an application with windows 10 firewall

Tags: windows-firewall

I try to block chrome and firefox from accessing the internet with Windows 10 Firewall but I get no result.

I blocked google chrome and firefox on the panel "allow an app or feature through Windows Firewall".

I also changed the inbound rules to "block the connexion" for those two applications.

And, as you can see, I'm still browsing.

I saw that Avast could interfere, so I totally uninstalled it and it's still working.

What am I missing ?

Thanks !

EDIT : Okay, the outbound rule did the trick, but why the inbound rule doesn't ?

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/227093/how-to-block-an-application-from-accessing-the-internet-with-windows-firewall/

Comment: Thanks, it helped ! I just don't understand why the outbound rules blocks successfully but not the inbound rule

Comment: Did you try with `netsh` command in CMD or `New-NetFirewallRule` cmdlet in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

i dont know wich version of window you use but this probably still works.

press winkey + r

a little box shos up then type

FIREWALL.CPL

press ok

find the allow a program or feature through windows firewall.

press change setting
select the programs you want to stop giving acces and press ok and your done :D

Comment: I use Windows 10 and when I uncheck the boxes for firefox and chrome that doesn't change anything at all. Just to be complete I can't uncheck both public and private boxes for firefox but normally since I uncheck the main box it should block.

Comment: Same problem here. And after unchecking the leftmost box, there is no OK button to accept the changes??